# CardView in RecyclerView - spinners

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am following g this tutorial https://inducesmile.com/android/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-material-design-tutorial/

My previous app file had it so the spinners were populated by a csv file. Now I am just making another app file because I wanted to start again by using cardviews and recyclerview.

However I am having some trouble with trying to implement my previous spinner code into this new app file using recycler views and cardviews.

The Example linked above calls for a class called ItemObject.java. I assum ed this is where I put the code that reads the csv.

**ItemObject class**

```
public class ItemObject {


    Spinner spinner;

    public void setText(String spinner) {


        private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();


        private class CSVFile {
            InputStream inputStream;

            public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
                this.inputStream = inputStream;
            }

            public List<String> read() {

                List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                try {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] row = line.split(",");
                        //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                        numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                        resultList.add(row[1]);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                return resultList;
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Then the example calls for a RecyclerViewAdatper. **I am confused what to put in the OnBindViewHolder part.** What is suppose to go in there, to do with my spinner?

**RecyclerViewAdapter class**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {

       // **WHAT TO PUT HERE**


        //holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}
```

And here is the RecyclerViewHolders class just for anyones reference.

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView countryName;
    public ImageView countryPhoto;
    public Spinner spinner;
    public TextView textView5;
    public CheckBox checkBox;
    public EditText editText;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*    countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);*/
        spinner = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        textView5 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        editText = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass CSV values in an String Array form to your recyleview adpater constructor. You can use these values to populate your spinner something like this

```
 String [] spinnerValues; 
 public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList, String [] spinnerValues) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
    this.spinnerValues = spinnerValues 
}
```

Make View Holder class a inner class in your adapter and use below code.

```
spinner = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, YOUR_STRING_ARRAY); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: is that in the onBindViewHolder in the Recyclerviewadapter class?